# Reading only x amount of bytes from a binary file

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, file-io

```
def streamView(request):
    # zip_path = './pages/data.zip'
    zip_path = './pages/data/test.txt'
    start_index = 0
    end_index = 50
    with open(zip_path, 'rb', 50) as fin:
        fin.seek(start_index)
        data = fin.read(end_index - start_index)
        response = HttpResponse(fin, content_type="application/zip")
        response["Content-Disposition"] = f"attachment; filename={zip_path}"
        return response
```

So I'm using the above code to read just the first 50 bits of a file and return them. However, this just returns the entire file to the user.

Ideally, I would like to send start and end parameters to this function, and then just read between those two points, and send that data.

How can I acheive this?

Comment: All I had to do was change the response to return data instead of fin

Comment: So does this mean you have answered your own question?  If, yes first of all congratulations, second could you add your solution as an answer and then accept the answer for posterity?